# Wrap figure first line alignment changed when using right alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, wrapfigure

Text properly aligned with wrap figure images on justify alignment, in the case of right alignment text, first line break with two or three words even the space occurs to fill the gap. Please suggest how to fix this problem. Here I attached screen shot both type of cases.

MWE:
[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{wrapfig}    
%\usepackage{fontspec}

\raggedright\parindent12pt

\begin{document}
\section{Overview}
Numerous videos
and interactivities are embedded just
where you need them, at the point of

\subsection{Links with our times}
When a new pipes are installed to take away sewage and
stormwater. All these facilities are
usually in place before any homes are built,
and even the construction of the
houses is governed by strict building regulations.
The situation was very
different two hundred years ago.

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{150pt}
\includegraphics{176774415.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}
When a new pipes are installed to take away sewage and
stormwater. All these facilities are
usually in place before any homes are built,
and even the construction of the
houses is governed by strict building regulations.
The situation was very
different two hundred years ago.


When a new pipes are installed to take away sewage and
stormwater. All these facilities are
usually in place before any homes are built,
and even the construction of the
houses is governed by strict building regulations.
The situation was very
different two hundred years ago.

\end{document}
```

Comment: With narrow columns it helps to use \sloppy (default is \fussy).